# Multiple reminders in single iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, reminders

how can we set more than one reminder's in our iPhone app, i have to set individual reminder's for every image projects in my app so that a user can take image (daily, weekly or monthly) from the camera for a specific project, i am able to set single reminder but when i tried to set more than one reminder for another project in my app it overwrites all the previous reminders of all projects. please give me any idea.

Comment: UILocalNotification.....

Comment: You should probably post some code you would like fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
 //KeyValue = used for identifying reminder
    //RepeatType = NSWeekCalendarUnit or NSMonthCalendarUnit
    //AlertBody = display text

    -(void)setReminder:(NSDate*)date KeyValue:(NSString*)keyValue RepeatType:(NSInteger)repeatType AlertBody:(NSString*)alertBody
    {
        UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        if (localNotif == nil)
            return;

        localNotif.fireDate = date;
        localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        // Notification details
        localNotif.alertBody = alertBody;

        // Set the action button
        localNotif.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View",nil);

        localNotif.soundName =UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

        // Specify custom data for the notification
        NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",keyValue] forKey:@"ReminderID"];

        localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;
        localNotif.repeatInterval = repeatType;

        // Schedule the notification
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

        [localNotif release];


    }
```

//call this method for setting single notification.
//you can set as many as you want